# Angular 2 NG-Completer calling keyup event twice?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a simple  element inside my HTML. When a key is released inside of it, a call is made to a method that writes to the console. The issue I'm having is that the console is being written to twice. So I'm assuming that (keyup) is being hit twice, am I right?

Here is my `ng2=completer`:

```
<ng2-completer #from [(ngModel)]="fromSearch" [datasource]="airportCodeList" [minSearchLength]="0" (keyup)="onKey()"></ng2-completer>
```

Below is the `onKey` method being called:

```
onKey(entry: string) {
  console.log("Key Pressed"); 
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Problem plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/sVnfpBiEb5jBdtul4ls9?p=preview), I can see its firing 4 times

Comment: Looks like this is a Angular bug and it was fixed? https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4611

Comment: Hi, I'm the author of ng2-completer can you open it as an issue in ng2-completer [github repo](https://github.com/oferh/ng2-completer/issues)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put ng2-completer into a div and move (keyup)="onKey()" to the div like:

```
<div (keyup)="onKey()">
  <ng2-completer #from [(ngModel)]="fromSearch" 
 [datasource]="airportCodeList" [minSearchLength]="0"></ng2-completer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is because the author of the component handled the keyUp event twice.
Evidences :

Source Code **[Link](https://github.com/oferh/ng2-completer/blob/master/src/components/completer-cmp.ts)**
 [image]

Also, he handles the keyUp event in the directive

Source Code **[Link](https://github.com/oferh/ng2-completer/blob/master/src/directives/ctr-input.ts)** 
[image]